# Setting properties of object

Tags: c#, linq

I want to get a list of a object by LINQ query. The problem is that I need to set properties of that object but those properties aren't set in its constructor.

```
categories.Select(c => new { c.catId, c.catName, c.catParent })
          .Where(c => c.catParent == id)
          .AsEnumerable()
          .Select(c => new CatInfoType())
          .ToList();
```

For example in Select I need to set public properties of CatInfoType instances like Id, Name etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [object initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx)

```
new CatInfoType
{
    PropertyX = 1,
    PropertyY = 2,
};
```

or

```
.Select(c =>
{
    var r = new CatInfoType();
    r.X = 1;
    r.Y = 2;
    return r;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You either want to create a constructor that takes those arguments or use static initilization meaning something like;

```
   Select(c => new CatInfoType {
              Id = c.Id,
              Name = c.Name  
        };)
```

Constructor route;

```
   // in CatInfoType class
   public CatInfoType(string name, string id)
   {
         Name = name;
         Id = id;
   }

   Select(c => new CatInfoType(c.Name, c.Id))
```